# DateTime object is none -- Python

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm doing this inside Django. The DateTime string is passed into POST successfully. This is my code:

```
vk = Vk()
day1 = request.POST['day1']
vk.day1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(day1, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
vk.save()
```

This is the format of the POST info:

```
'day1': 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM' # AM/PM meaning either AM or PM
```

The problem is that the `DateTimeField` on the vk instance is `None`.

```
class Vk(models.Model):
    day1 = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I see that it is None in my HTML file:

```
{% for vk in vk %}
{{ vk.day1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

which amounts to None.

This is the view that is responsible for rendering the template:

```
def list_verkefni(request):
    vk = Vk.objects.all()
    vm = Vm.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'list_verkefni.html', 
    {'vk': vk, 'vm': vm}
    )
```

Comment: Updated the Original post

Comment: Thanks. How do you check that the value of `day1` is saved as `None`?

Comment: Updated the OP again. I have faith in the template, but I'll check the console just in case

Comment: Good, then what is `Vk` variable passed to the template? Could you show the view which is responsible for rendering the template?

Comment: Updated, but I can confirm that the view is working correctly because it is displaying other attributes (unrelated) of Vk correctly

Comment: Where are you saving the `vk` instance? Is it wrapped it a try/except statement?

Comment: Not sure if I understand first question. I did not use a try/except statement.

Comment: I just want to be sure that your code is actually saving your instance and not hiding a validation error.

Comment: I now did a try/except and it was successful. Man this is mysterious.

Comment: Try changing `day1` to `DateField` instead of `DateTimeField` just for debugging purpose and see if that works.

Comment: The issue could be with the conflicting loop variable -> do `{% for v in vk %}` instead of `{% for vk in vk %}`. If this does not solve the issue, Another thing I would do is in the view, `print list(vk.values_list('day1', flat=True))` to see if the values are stored properly.

Comment: Dire news - the result is the same. I tried both your suggestions

Comment: Wait, what? Suddenly, it works. After changing the DateFields back to DateTimeFields .......

Comment: I think I know what went wrong. It was most likely a discrepancy between the model and what I expected - Now, my old times (I had them with DateField long ago) are None, just like my new fields with DateTimeField, which are now working as normal. If you're having the same problem as me, make sure your models are built correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use ModelForm?

someapp/forms.py:

```
class VkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vk
        fields = ('day1', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['day1'].input_formats = ['%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', ]
```

someapp/views.py:

```
def myview(request):
    form = VkForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/somewhere/')
    return render(
        request, 'template.html',
        {'form': form}
    )
```

Yes, you write a little bit more code, but:

- you get full validation with nice error messages
- whenever you extend your model in future, you don't need to rewrite the code, just add the field name into ModelForm
- you don't need to do low level conversion to Python data types

This is considered a bad practise:

```
{% for vk in vk %}
{{ vk.day1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Although this works in Django template engine, it is very confusing. If you would write the same in Python, `vk` will be overwritten. Whenever you work with a list of items, append `_list` to the variable name, e.g.: `object_list` or `vk_list` to distinguish between a single object and a list.

To better debug a code, I would suggest to pip install pudb and do something like this:

```
vk = Vk()
day1 = request.POST['day1']
import pudb; pudb.set_trace()
vk.day1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(day1, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
vk.save()
```

Run the local dev server, do the POST request and check your terminal. Check if `request.POST['day1']` is really what you expect to be and if it the datetime instance was set on your `day` atribute.

Comment: Thanks, this would have saved me a lot of headache I think. I'll do this.